# How to calculate sum if entry falls in date interval in R?

Tags: r, date, sum, data.table, intervals

I have two data frames, one of which (`df`) contains every week in a time series, and a units amount for each week. This is grouped by ID.

The other frame (`df2`) contains each ID, a start date column, and a corresponding stop date column. Some IDs in this frame have multiple start and stop entries.

I would like to calculate the sum of the units column if the date of the units entry falls in the start/stop window for that ID.

The desired output would be a summed units column in the second frame, where a units total is assigned to each start/stop row for an ID.

I have tried using the `lubridate` package and the interval function to accomplish this. I have also tried using a `data.table` and calculating the sum on instances of weeks that fall in the desired interval.

```
library(lubridate)

df2$interval <- interval(ymd(df2$start), ymd(df2$stop))


output <- do.call(rbind, lapply(df$Week, function(x){
  index <- x %within% df2$interval;
  list(Units = sum(df$Units[index]))
}))
```

But this errors with

> Error in .setupMethodsTables(fdef, initialize = TRUE) : no slot of name "group" for this object of class "derivedDefaultMethod"

I have also tried:

```
df[df2, on = .(start <= Week, Week>stop), allow = TRUE
   ][ , .(df2$sumUnits = sum(Units))]
```

But the error this time is

> Error: unexpected '=' in: "df[df2, on = .(start <= Week, Week>stop), allow = TRUE][ , .(df2$sumUnits ="

Comment: Try `.(sumUnits = sum(Units))`? `list(df2$sumUnits = sum(Units))` is not valid syntax (`.` is an alias for `list` in `data.table`)

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out Michael! I adjusted the syntax according to your suggestion, and was returned the error message: Error in `[.data.frame`(df, df2, on = .(start <=  : 
  unused arguments (on = .(start <= Week, Week > stop), allow = TRUE)

Comment: you need `setDT(df)` and `setDT(df2)` as well